# Why Ewald–Oseen extinction theorem failed to explain refraction

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, refraction

One way to understand the refraction of light other than Huygens–Fresnel principle is by Ewald–Oseen extinction theorem, which states that light scatters only in forward direction with a slower velocity. And then we can use Fermat's law to derive Snell's law. However, microscopically, Ewald-Oseen theorem failed to explain why light should change direction inside medium, where does this failure comes from?

Comment: Don’t think the theorem states that light is only scattered in the forward direction. It’s usually derived/proven for normal incidence (for which the *coherent* component of light is indeed transmitted in the forward direction) in textbooks for simplicity, but the proof involves a symmetry argument that’s broken for oblique incidence. It isn’t that the theorem doesn’t work, but that the derivation you find in textbooks doesn’t account for oblique incidence.